# Future-Proof Encrypt for Multiple Independent Parties

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

I have a secret message which I want to encrypt such that any of several different keys can open it independently.  The keys can't know about each other and it has to be able to work completely locally without a network. In short I want two functions

```
encrypt(message, key1, key2, key3, ...) -> code
decrypt(code, keyX) -> message                   for keyX in (key1, key2, key3...)
decrypt(code, keyY) -> random                    for keyY not (key1, key2, key3...)
```

Ideally these functions would also have the property that

```
encrypt(message, key1) -> code1   decrypt(code1, key1) -> message
encrypt(code1, key2) -> code2     decrypt(code2, key1) -> message, decrypt(code2, key2) -> message
```

This seems like it should be relatively possible to do but I can't figure out how to do it yet. In my research I came across similar problems which many people were calling broadcast encryption but when I read up on it, it seems like for most broadcast encryption schemes require that you broadcast some information about what set of people are allowed to unlock the content and this is used by everyone to calculate their new keys.  This isn't want I want. I need that the "locks" can't change and that adding a new lock doesn't invalidate the old ones.

A physical metaphor would be if you were locking a box lid to bottom using some number of padlocks.  The system I am looking for would be like a chain of padlocks so that opening any of them separates the top from the bottom of the box.  Furthermore, if you add another new padlock on the end of the chain somehow, any of the original keys are still just as useful at opening the whole box.  Anyone have some ideas or links to read up on? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a standard encryption method, let 
code(i) = encrypt([key(i), message], key(i)) 
(where [A,B] is concatenation of A and B, with a publicly-known separator), and
code = [code(1), code(2), ..., code(n)]
To decrypt code with a key, you try decrypt(code(i), key) for each i = 1 .. n
and see which result starts with your key; the rest of the result is then the
message.